# Is there a way to move style object in PaperProps to makeStyles in material UI?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Material UI Menu component and try to customize its border. I'm only able to do it via PaperProps inline on the Menu element. But I already have a makeStyles object. Is there a way to add that style customization to makeStyles?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    ...
  }
}
...
<Menu
  PaperProps={{
    style: { borderRadius: 1 },
  }}
  className={ classes.root }
>
{props.children}
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the `classes` property of `<Menu />`

Check the **CSS** section at https://material-ui.com/api/menu/

Classes property accepts an object with the key denoting the style rule to update..

To override paper styles, you can do

```
<Menu
      id="simple-menu"
      open={true}
      classes={{
        paper: classes.custom
      }}
    >
```

A complete example might look like....

```
import React from "react";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

function App() {
  const useStyles = makeStyles({
    custom: {
      borderColor: "green",
      borderWidth: "2px",
      borderStyle: "solid"
    },
    list: {
      backgroundColor: "yellow"
    }
  });

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Menu
      id="simple-menu"
      open={true}
      classes={{
        paper: classes.custom,
        list: classes.list
      }}
    >
      <MenuItem>Item 1</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>Item 2</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>Item 3</MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  );
}

export default App;
```